Bulk API query - escaping quotes in JSON payload
I am building an app to access and curate data from a salesforce installation. We will be organizing manufacturing companies, but many companies inside the salesforce DB are non manufacturing. In the Customer_Group__c field, it's listed as "Manufacturing" or "Non-Manufacturing"
When I query fields from all companies via cur ("SELECT ID, Name, Customer_Group__c FROM Account"), this works.
curl https://[url]/services/data/v60.0/jobs/query -H "Authorization: Bearer [Access Token]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1" --data-raw '{"operation":"query","query":"SELECT ID, Name, Customer_Group__c FROM Account"}' -X POST

This returns like 20,000 records, once I request it after the job is finished.
Now when I try to limit the query to only Manufacturing (about 10,000 records) ("SELECT ID, Name, Customer_Group__c FROM Account WHERE Customer_Group__c='Manufacturing'"), it always fails.
curl https://[url]/services/data/v60.0/jobs/query -H "Authorization: Bearer [Access Token]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1" --data-raw '{"operation":"query","query":"SELECT ID, Name, Customer_Group__c FROM Account WHERE Customer_Group__c='Manufacturing'"}' -X POST

It returns the following error
   Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errorCode] => INVALIDJOB
            [message] => Query parsing error: rule parseSingleWhere failed predicate: {c != null}?
        )

)

The most bizarre thing - when I enter the query in the developer console, it works.
I've had phone calls with Salesforce tech support, then cannot figure this out.
Any ideas?

I'm assuming you need to escape the single quotes in your query.

tried that, still failed. Will try again.

Now got this error
'Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[errorCode] => API_ERROR
[message] => Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING at [line:1, column:241]
)
)

The format of the error message indicates you're executing curl from PHP. The comment by Nick is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122586/curl-escape-single-quote shows how to do this generally speaking. Correctly escaping quotes does make this work with curl and SF.

Followed instructions there. Changed query to -

"SELECT ID, Name, Customer_Group__c FROM Account WHERE Customer_Group__c='''Manufacturing'''"
Now get this error -
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[errorCode] => API_ERROR
[message] => Unrecognized character escape 'M' (code 77) at [line:1, column:105]
)
)
